# Magento: Store, Store view, Website in transaction

Tags: php, web, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I have small problem about store, store view and website creation. I create the store on the customer register (one customer has one website, one store view and one store), all is ok, but when there is an error in saving for example store view, other elements in the DB.

The code:

```
// Root Category
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->setStoreId(0);
$category->save();

// Website
$website = new Mage_Core_Model_Website();
$website->setData(array(
    'code' => $codes,
    'sort_order' => 10
))->save();

// Create store group (store view)
$storeGroup = new Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group();
$storeGroup->setData(array(
    'website_id' => $website->getId(),
    'root_category_id' => $category->getId()
))->save();

// Create store
$store = new Mage_Core_Model_Store();
$store->setData(array(
    'code' => $codes,
    'website_id' => $website->getId(),
    'group_id' => $storeGroup->getId(),
));
$store->save();
```

I need to edit the code so this things will create in transaction and rollback if there is an error. I don't know how to do this, because I need an id after each object save.

Answer (score 2):

ok, solved myself

```
try {
    $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    $write->beginTransaction();

    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->setStoreId(0)
                    ->setName($code)
                    ->setParentId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::TREE_ROOT_ID)
                    ->setPath(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::TREE_ROOT_ID)
                    ->setDisplayMode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DM_PRODUCT)
                    ->setIsActive(TRUE)
                    ->setId(NULL)
                    ->save();
    $website = Mage::getModel('core/website')
                   ->setCode($code)
                   ->setName($code)
                   ->setSortOrder(10)
                   ->setId(NULL)
                   ->save();
    $storegr = Mage::getModel('core/store_group')
                   ->setWebsiteId($website->getId())
                   ->setName($code)
                   ->setRootCategoryId($category->getId())
                   ->setId(NULL)
                   ->save();
    $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')
                 ->setCode('1'.$code)
                 ->setWebsiteId($website->getId())
                 ->setGroupId($storegr->getId())
                 ->setName($code)
                 ->setSortOrder(10)
                 ->setIsActive(TRUE)
                 ->setId(NULL)
                 ->save();
    $write->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $write->rollback();
}
```

Comment: No need to mark questions as solved manually - just award yourself a tick next to your answer `:)`. +1